# Library for kademila end emule

Tags: java, python, ruby

Anyone known a ruby (or at least python or java) library for kademila and emule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmule/  - active, not lib but I guess that UI can be cutoff - however it may need some Java coding.

Another option: Use mldonkey gui protocol to control mldonkey instance http://mldonkey.sourceforge.net/GuiProtocol .

eDonkey2000 is proprietary protocol and nobody wants to invest in it thus no serious solutions.

It is easier to find BitTorrent library implementations as they are used and developed also in commercial software for CDN.